# Could any of the ancients still be alive?

Tags: stargate

I've currently been re-watching the *Stargate* series and my question is as follows:

**Could it be possible that any of the ancients may still be alive?**

As we know, some are still aboard their ships in stasis pods, but they can't be taken out because it would kill them.

**Is there any back story or any other information (possibly in comic books) out there that tells us more?**

Comment: Are you asking about the species that became the ancients, or the ancients themselves? Because all the transcended ancients are very much alive.

Comment: There was an episode in Stargate Atlantis where an Ancient ship had a broken hyperdrive that was unrepairable. It was traveling back to Atlantis at near light speeds using it's normal propulsion engines when it just so happened to cross paths with a ship from Earth. Long story short, the Earth ship took them to Atlantis, they evicted the humans, the replicators came back (which were modified by Kay previously), and the replicators took over Atlantis killing the Ancients there. This could be a good basis for an answer depending on what you mean by "still".

Comment: Orlin is an ancient. He was [briefly alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_characters_in_Stargate#Orlin) in SG1

Comment: Ayiana was discovered in an suspension pod in Antartica; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_characters_in_Stargate#Ayiana

Comment: In SGA: The Return, an entire ship filled with ancients was discovered. Their ship was traveling at sublight speeds and had experienced time dilation; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stargate_Atlantis_(season_3)#ep50

Comment: @Richard: That's the episode I was thinking of (your third comment). I couldn't remember the details.

Answer (score 14):

I assume that by "alive", you are also meaning "mortal" and not ascended (since there are an uncounted number of those, with Morgan Le Fay and Oma Desala being notable ones). There are several Ancients that were alive and mortal during the course of the series, although most of them eventually died:

- **[Ayiana](http://gateworld.net/wiki/Ayiana)** (SG-1 Season 6, [Frozen](http://gateworld.net/sg1/s6/604.shtml)): Preserved in a block of ice in Antarctica near the second Stargate found there. Had a disease very similar to one that the Priors of the Ori eventually unleashed, and eventually succumbed to it.
- **[Orlin](http://gateworld.net/wiki/Orlin)** (SG-1 Season 9, [The Fourth Horseman, Part 2](http://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s9/911.shtml)): A previously ascended Ancient (encountered before by SG-1), he descended in order to provide an antidote to the plague the Priors had unleashed. The strain of having all his ascended knowledge in a mortal body eventually resulted in him having brain damage and forgetting what he knew. Orlin is the only Ancient who is still alive by the end of both series, albeit as a shell of his former self.
- **[Myrddin (Merlin)](http://gateworld.net/wiki/Myrddin)** (SG-1 Season 10, [The Quest, Part 2](http://www.gateworld.net/sg1/s10/1011.shtml)): Although seen in holograms in several episodes prior, SG-1 eventually found Merlin in a stasis pod where he taught Daniel Jackson how to construct the Sangraal (an anti-Ori weapon). He eventually died of the strain on his body.
- **A shipful of Ancients in stasis** (SGA Season 2, [Aurora](http://gateworld.net/atlantis/s2/209.shtml)): The Ancient warship Aurora is found where the crew are in stasis and live in a sort of virtual reality. Shepherd and McKay talk with them, but realize that even with stasis they have aged so much that they would die if removed. They discovered there was a Wraith impersonating an Ancient in the virtual reality and set the self-destruct on the ship in order to prevent information about a weakness to the Wraith from falling into their hands.*
- **A shipful of Ancients subject to time-dilation** (SGA Season 3, The Return [Part 1](http://gateworld.net/atlantis/s3/310.shtml) and [Part 2](http://gateworld.net/atlantis/s3/311.shtml)): An Ancient ship traveling just under the speed of light for thousands of years experienced time dilation and, when they slowed down, were perfectly healthy and took over Atlantis. They are eventually killed when human replicators attack Atlantis.**

While it's certainly possible that there are other Ancients who are preserved through some sort of stasis or also chose to descend, there are no clues that they exist. If they do exist, it seems that they do not want to be found, or don't have the means to broadcast their presence. Indeed, all of the Ancients, aside from Myrddin, were found by accident (including Orlin the first time they met).

<sub>* Sadly, this plot point of the Wraith having a weakness was never revisited</sub>
<sub>** These Ancients were jerks and wanted nothing to do with the Atlantis expedition. They didn't even bother to tell the crew what their name for a "puddlejumper" was!</sub>

Comment: You forgot Ganos Lal (Morgan le Fey) and Myrddin (Merlin). That aside, none of these are still alive. They each briefly returned to life, but by the end of each of their episode arcs they were all very much dead. But given how often SG1 and SGA have found non-ascended Ancients who were alive when found, it is likely that there are probably others still alive.

Comment: I did forget Merlin, I'll add him. But I thought Morgan Le Fay was ascended since she had to play by the Ancients' rules.

Comment: Technically, you've listed Ancients that *were* alive, but no longer are (Orlin is debatable, if he came back in a pure human body), and don't answer the question about current-living Ancients. I think a little speculation would answer it quite well!

Comment: @CreationEdge I meant to show Ancients that were alive during the course of the show; I've edited my answer to clarify. I also added a bit showing that while there could be more Ancients, there are no clues that there are some. Also, I had thought Orlin was in the body of an Ancient boy rather than a Human boy, although admittedly it's pretty much impossible to tell the difference.

Comment: Since Ancients had mastered time travel, living ones could pop up most any time.

Comment: Yeah, I guess Morgan Le Fey never did really return to mortal form. She just appeared as one like Oma Desala. Even at the end when she battled Adria, she was still an Ascended being.